# Triggers not working properly in Jquery slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slideshow

I made a slideshow in jquery but I am having a hard time to make a proper algorithm for triggers to become functional.
Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

[Demo available here](http://jsfiddle.net/tn29smrx/)

HTML

```
<div class=slide-show>
    <div id=slide1><h1>1</h1></div>
    <div id=slide2><h1>2</h1></div>
    <div id=slide3><h1>3</h1></div>
    <div id=slide4><h1>4</h1></div>
</div>
<div class=slide-controls>
    <div class=slide-controls-wrap>
        <ul style="float:left;">
            <li class=slide-cont id=1></li>
            <li class=slide-cont id=2></li>
            <li class=slide-cont id=3></li>
            <li class=slide-cont id=4></li>
        </ul>
        <ul style="float:right;margin-right:50px;margin-top:2px;">
            <li class=left-arrow></li>
            <li class=right-arrow></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var delayInterval = 5000;
    var delay = setTimeout;
    function slide_show(cont) {
        if (cont > 4) cont = 1;
        $("#slide" + cont).fadeIn(1500);
        $("#" + cont).css("background-position", '-69px -94px');
        delay(function () {
            $("#slide" + cont).fadeOut(1500);
            $("#" + cont).css("background-position", '-19px -94px');
            $('#1').click(function () {
                slide_show(1);
            });
            $('#2').click(function () {
                slide_show(2);
            });
            $('#3').click(function () {
                slide_show(3);
            });
            $('#4').click(function () {
                slide_show(4);
            });
            slide_show(cont + 1);    
            //$("#5").css("background-position",'-69px -94px');
        }, delayInterval);
    }
    slide_show(1);    
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Demo**: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/azpwMy

Here is a better function for you :)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.slide-cont').click(function(){
    var slideId = $(this).attr('id');
    currentSlide = slideId - 1;
    $(slides).hide();
    $('#slide' + slideId).fadeIn(1500);
  })
})
var slides = $('.slide-show div');
currentSlide = 0;

function changeSlide(n) {
    currentSlide += n;
    if (currentSlide > slides.length - 1)
        currentSlide = 0;
    else if(currentSlide < 0)
        currentSlide = slides.length -1;

   $(slides).hide();
    $(slides[currentSlide]).fadeIn(1500);
}
```

If you want to go one to the right you call with **changeSlide(1)**, to the left **changeSlide(-1)**

To change the current slide based on time.

```
//Go one slide to the right every 2 seconds
setInterval(function(){changeSlide(1)}, 2000);
```

Hope i helped!

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. If it was just about using arrows triggers, I would have preferred to use your function but I want disc triggers to work as well.

Comment: Oh! here is a full demo of the implementation i made http://codepen.io/anon/pen/azpwMy

Comment: I think its much cleaner, if you have any questions, just ask

Comment: I would highly appreciate your help in implementing the algorithm for discs triggers as well..

Comment: Sure! I forgot about that:) I just updated the answer :)

Comment: You have been so helpful, thank you so much!!! lastly I would ask can you please make the previous slide fadeout while making the current slide fadeIn? because it makes some sort of confusion in functioning disc triggers.

Comment: One more thing when disc trigger is clicked, the slideshow starts from one slide behind the clicked trigger...

Comment: Thats because I forgot the $(slides).hide(); line. Just updated the answer.

Comment: Can you validate the last error again ? That don't make sense

Comment: Just updated the demo link and tested. Should be working fine now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68442/discussion-between-tka-and-kaue-gimenes).